# How do you delete a file in ubuntu?

Tags: files, root, delete

I need to delete a file how do i do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting a file owned by root](http://askubuntu.com/questions/146384/deleting-a-file-owned-by-root)

Comment: Please, read http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask especially the part on showing in the question the effort you did to solve it, and what you tried. As it is, the only possible answer is "it depends"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to delete a file in Ubuntu, we can use the standard command `rm` in Ubuntu Terminal.
However, there are some precaution, for example about the ownership of the file/ folder.

For more detail instruction, please look at:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DeletingFiles

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file you wish to remove and select 'Move to the rubbish bin' then empty the rubbish bin.

If you need to delete files owned by root open a ctrl/alt T type:-

```
gksu nautilus
```

this should open a window navigate to the file and delete as above.